# Apache Flink - How to load a csv DataSet with a date data in it?

Tags: java, apache-flink

//My code below returns an error "The type 'java.util.Date' is not supported for the CSV input format".

final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

```
    DataSource<org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3<Date ,Double,Integer>> csvInput = env.readCsvFile("/home/work/Desktop/Test2.csv")
            .ignoreFirstLine()
            .types(Date.class, Double.class, Integer.class);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a source function that transform the string to date. Here is one example from the FLink training [TaxiRideSource](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ververica/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_java/sources/TaxiRideSource.java). and here is my example which is very similar:

```
public class TaxiRide implements Comparable<TaxiRide>, Serializable {

    private static final transient DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter =
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withLocale(Locale.US).withZoneUTC();
    public long rideId;
    public boolean isStart;
    public DateTime startTime;
    public DateTime endTime;
    public float startLon;
    public float startLat;
    public float endLon;
    public float endLat;
    public short passengerCnt;
    public long taxiId;
    public long driverId;
    public TaxiRide() {
        this.startTime = new DateTime();
        this.endTime = new DateTime();
    }
    public TaxiRide(long rideId, boolean isStart, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime,
                    float startLon, float startLat, float endLon, float endLat,
                    short passengerCnt, long taxiId, long driverId) {

        this.rideId = rideId;
        this.isStart = isStart;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.startLon = startLon;
        this.startLat = startLat;
        this.endLon = endLon;
        this.endLat = endLat;
        this.passengerCnt = passengerCnt;
        this.taxiId = taxiId;
        this.driverId = driverId;
    }

    public static TaxiRide fromString(String line) {

        String[] tokens = line.split(",");
        if (tokens.length != 11) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid record: " + line);
        }

        TaxiRide ride = new TaxiRide();

        try {
            ride.rideId = Long.parseLong(tokens[0]);

            switch (tokens[1]) {
                case "START":
                    ride.isStart = true;
                    ride.startTime = DateTime.parse(tokens[2], timeFormatter);
                    ride.endTime = DateTime.parse(tokens[3], timeFormatter);
                    break;
                case "END":
                    ride.isStart = false;
                    ride.endTime = DateTime.parse(tokens[2], timeFormatter);
                    ride.startTime = DateTime.parse(tokens[3], timeFormatter);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException("Invalid record: " + line);
            }

            ride.startLon = tokens[4].length() > 0 ? Float.parseFloat(tokens[4]) : 0.0f;
            ride.startLat = tokens[5].length() > 0 ? Float.parseFloat(tokens[5]) : 0.0f;
            ride.endLon = tokens[6].length() > 0 ? Float.parseFloat(tokens[6]) : 0.0f;
            ride.endLat = tokens[7].length() > 0 ? Float.parseFloat(tokens[7]) : 0.0f;
            ride.passengerCnt = Short.parseShort(tokens[8]);
            ride.taxiId = Long.parseLong(tokens[9]);
            ride.driverId = Long.parseLong(tokens[10]);

        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid record: " + line, nfe);
        }

        return ride;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(rideId).append(",");
        sb.append(isStart ? "START" : "END").append(",");
        sb.append(startTime.toString(timeFormatter)).append(",");
        sb.append(endTime.toString(timeFormatter)).append(",");
        sb.append(startLon).append(",");
        sb.append(startLat).append(",");
        sb.append(endLon).append(",");
        sb.append(endLat).append(",");
        sb.append(passengerCnt).append(",");
        sb.append(taxiId).append(",");
        sb.append(driverId);

        return sb.toString();
    }

    // sort by timestamp,
    // putting START events before END events if they have the same timestamp
    public int compareTo(TaxiRide other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        int compareTimes = Long.compare(this.getEventTime(), other.getEventTime());
        if (compareTimes == 0) {
            if (this.isStart == other.isStart) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                if (this.isStart) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return compareTimes;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other instanceof TaxiRide &&
            this.rideId == ((TaxiRide) other).rideId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) this.rideId;
    }

    public long getEventTime() {
        if (isStart) {
            return startTime.getMillis();
        } else {
            return endTime.getMillis();
        }
    }

    public double getEuclideanDistance(double longitude, double latitude) {
        if (this.isStart) {
            return GeoUtils.getEuclideanDistance((float) longitude, (float) latitude, this.startLon, this.startLat);
        } else {
            return GeoUtils.getEuclideanDistance((float) longitude, (float) latitude, this.endLon, this.endLat);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so does this mean that in order for me to load a date type of data, i need to create an additional function to transform from string to date?

Comment: you don't have to create another function if you don't want. You can use data type serializer (https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html). However I think it is cleaner to create a function. It is up to you.

Comment: maybe you can approve the answer?